# Merging dataframes without sorting the values

Tags: r

I have two dataframes.

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c(1, 5, 3))
df2 = data.frame(x=c(2, 4, 6))
```

When i merge the both, I get the numbers sorted out

```
merge(df1, df2, all =  TRUE)



 x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

However , I want the number as it is in the order given in the data frames

something like

```
x
    1 1
    2 5
    3 3
    4 2
    5 4
    6 6
```

The above solution can be achieved if i put the data in quotes like below, but in my work scenario i cannot do that.

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c('1', '5', '3'))
    df2 = data.frame(x=c('2', '4', '6'))
```

How can i get the merged dataframe created without sorting the values?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); full_join(df1, df2)`

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
merge(df1, df2, all =  TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
  x
1 1
2 5
3 3
4 2
5 4
6 6
```